# Angular MatDialog testing with Jest

Tags: angular, angular-material, jestjs

Here is a pretty simple Angular component that I would like to test with Jest:

```
export class EmployeeComponent {

  employees: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  onOpenDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(NewEmployeeDialogComponent)
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(filter(employee => employee))
      .subscribe(employee => this.employees.push(employee));
  }
}
```

No matter how much I try, I cannot find an elegant solution to mock open() and afterClosed() calls. Unless, I overwrite the dialog value directly in the class above which is terrible hacky solution. :(

```
describe('EmployeeComponent', () => {

  let component: EmployeeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EmployeeComponent>;
  const mockMatDialog = { open: jest.fn() };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EmployeeComponent, NewEmployeeDialogComponent, EmployeeListComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatSelectModule
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: MatDialog, useValue: mockMatDialog }],
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [NewEmployeeDialogComponent]
      }
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmployeeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should open the dialog and save a valid employee', () => {
    component.dialog = TestBed.get(MatDialog);
    spyOn(TestBed.get(MatDialog), 'open').and.returnValue({afterClosed: () => of(employee)});
    component.openDialog();
    expect(component.employees).toStrictEqual([employee]);
  });
});
```

Do you have any advice how it can be tested nicely?

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this. This is how I solved it using jest, spectator, and ng-mocks.

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
let spectator: Spectator<SomeComponent>;
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: SomeComponent,
  mocks: [MatDialog, MatDialogRef],
  declarations: [
    MockComponent(MyDialogComponent)
  ]
  });
beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

describe('dialogTest', () => {

  test('return data from dialog', () => {
    const myDialog = spectator.inject<MatDialog>(MatDialog);
    // could also be <MatDialogRef<any, any>>(MatDialogRef)
    // I just happened to have a data type I was returning
    const myDialogRef = spectator.inject<MatDialogRef<MyDialogData, any>>(MatDialogRef);
    jest.spyOn(myDialog, 'open').mockReturnValue(myDialogRef);
    jest.spyOn(myDialogRef, 'afterClosed').mockReturnValue(of({aValue: true, bValue: false}));
    // insert call to function on the component that makes the dialog.open() call
    // for me it was triggering a UI event
    expect(myDialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(MyDialogComponent, expect.anything());
 myDialog.closeAll();
 // insert expectations of calls made based on the return values from MatDialogRef
 // for me these were ngrx dispatch calls, but could also be confirming the values set on SomeComponent based on the returns from MatDialogRef
 });
```